# open_basedir in reverse… kind of…

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, open-basedir

We have several vhosts that all include files from another vhost so in the httpd.conf we have added

```
php_admin_value open_basedir "..........:/home/commonfi"
```

I was wondering whether I could add something to the commonfi vhost setup to allow any site to access the files without having to specify /home/commonfi in the open_basedir for every other vhost.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to explicitly specify the path.